# Saving small sub-dataframes containing all values associated to a specific 'key' string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd need a little suggestion on a procedure using pandas, I have a 2-columns dataset that looks like this:

```
A      0.4533
B      0.2323
A      1.2343
A      1.2353
B      4.3521
C      3.2113
C      2.1233
..      ...
```

where first column contains strings and the second one floats. I would like to save the minimum value for each group of unique strings in order to have the associated minimum with `A, B, C`. Does anybody have any suggestions on that? It could help me also storing somehow all the values for each string they are associated.

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df
   0       1
0  A  0.4533
1  B  0.2323
2  A  1.2343
3  A  1.2353
4  B  4.3521
5  C  3.2113
6  C  2.1233
```

Use `groupby` before `min`:

```
out = df.groupby(0).min()
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
        1
0
A  0.4533
B  0.2323
C  2.1233
```

**Update**:

> filter out all the values in the original dataset that are more than 20% different from the minimum

```
out = df[df.groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda x: x <= x.min() * 1.2)]
```

```
>>> out
   0       1
0  A  0.4533
1  B  0.2323
6  C  2.1233
```

Comment: Thanks this actually helped.. What I would like to do is filter out all the values in the original dataset that are more than 20% different from the minimum.. Is this straightforward as well?

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: many many thanks! The only thing is that I do not mean the absolute minimum, but the minimum according to the subgroup. For example, if the minimum value associated to 'A' is 0.1, I wanna filter out all the values associated to the key 'A' that differ more than the 20% of 0.1 and likely for any other key

Comment: Why do you removed your vote??? My answer takes into account of the minimum + 20% of each group

Comment: sorry about that, I just had that final perplexity, but now everything’s clear. Thanks again for you help 

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by

```
min_A=min(df[df["column_1"]=="A"]["value"])
min_B=min(df[df["column_1"]=="B"]["value"])
min_C=min(df[df["column_1"]=="C"]["value"])
```

where *`df`* = Dataframe 
 *`column_1 and value`* are the names of the columns of the dataframe 
 
You can also do it by using the pre-defined function of `pandas` i.e. *`groupby()`*

```
>> df.groupby(["column_1"]).min()
```

The Above will also give the same results.